# JavaScript - insert random numbers/variables into a dynamic hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, random, hyperlink

This is my first HTML JavaScript, I want to generate a random HTML link by JavaScript containing semi random words and numbers to search for random intellectual / mysterious articles.

For example:

- google search "Wiki Born (Random number 1400-1850)" >>> Find random
  post dark ages biography
- google search "unexplained (Random number 1900 1930)" >>> Find random
  unexplained event

Comment: How about a google search "javascript random number"? StackOverflow is here to help you with coding problems, but not to write all of your code for you from scratch...

Comment: Anyone one can do a random number, that is so easy, the difficult think is putting the variable in the link code, i write tons of actionscript and never did javascript. I just thought it might take 3 lines for someone to write, and 2 hours for me to figure out alone. i am slow!

Comment: If you find the random number part so easy then please show the code you have so far and we can help you with the bit you're stuck on. Do you have code yet to do a non-random google search?

Comment: Can you explain to me how to reasearch such semantically nebulous terms as Javascript Google Search (i.e. generate, code, ) ...it's more thank just a google search it's abit technical searching code for internet code.

Comment: You don't. Break the problem down into the obvious component parts (such as generating a random number) and deal with them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for helping a Newbie!!!..... OK i have ascertained that the question is technically **"how to insert a variable into a dynamic hyperlink"** so i found this code   `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = 10; 
</script>
<a href="2.html" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+scrt_var;return false;">Link</a> `  although it didnt work, i am using it in Blogger.com and i didnt see any hyperlink... so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to [generate a random link with a random number on page load](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/pyeWK/):

```
var searches = [
    ['Wiki Born', 1400, 1850, 'post dark ages biography'],
    ['unexplained', 1900, 1930, 'unexplained event']
];
var google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

function getRand(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min));
}

window.onload = function() {
    // get random search item
    var item = searches[getRand(0, searches.length)];

    // get random number based on the selected item
    var randnum = getRand(item[1], item[2]);

    // put together the google link, replace spaces with + sign
    var searchlink = (google + item[0] + ' ' + randnum).replace(/\s+/g, '+');
    console.log(searchlink);

    // put together the html tag
    var html = '<a href="'+searchlink+'" target="_blank">Find random '+item[3]+'</a>';
    console.log(html);

    document.body.innerHTML = html;
};
```

If you want to [display all links with their own random number on page load](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/Z4f9x/), add a loop:

```
// for each search item
for(i=0; i<searches.length; i++) {
    var item = searches[i];

....
```

If you want [each link to generate a different number each time it is clicked](http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/s8Zjz/), we can take a different approach:

```
<script>
function getRand(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min));
}

window.onload = function() {
    // get all links in the #randomlinks div
    var links = document.getElementById('randomlinks').getElementsByTagName('a');

    // for each search item
    for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {

        // set a click handler
        links[i].onclick = function() {

            // get random number based on data attributes
            var min = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-min'), 10);
            var max = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-max'), 10);
            var randnum = getRand(min, max);

            // append random number to end of link
            this.href = this.href.replace(/\+[0-9]*$/, '+'+randnum);
        };
    }
};
</script>
<div id="randomlinks">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=Wiki+Born+" data-min="1400" data-max="1850" target="_blank">Find random post dark ages biography</a><br>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=unexplained+" data-min="1900" data-max="1930" target="_blank">Find random unexplained event</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou So much for this code! it's fantastic! I'd like to go for the 3rd option and i have an issue in Blogger, i have to put the <script>...</script> inside a <div>  and i tried various combinations of divider incapsulation and i get a result: https://www.google.com/search?q=Wiki+Born+        ...empty field. i dunno if i can post the code here ill try:      `Blogger HTML editor page

<br />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
funtion.....
 </script>



<br />
<div id="randomlinks">
<a data-max="1850" data-min="1400" href="http..earch?q=Wiki+Born+" target="_blank">title</a><br />
.....
</div>
`

Comment: sry my comment editing time ran out. on blogger it get result:  https://www.google.com/search?q=Wiki+Born+        ...empty field. i dunno if i can post the code here ill try:      `Blogger HTML editor page

<br /><div>   
<script type="text/javascript">     
funtion.....    
 </script>    
</div>   


<br />   
<div id="rnd...">   
<a data-max="1850" data-min="1400" href="http...?q=Wiki+Born+" target="_blank">title</a><br />   
.....
</div>   
`

Comment: Awesome man you are the best, i'll do a website now using all the html tricks i know... i know alot! Blogger made me waste 1 hour i just couldnt get it to work on there, and then i got a normal HTML site and it's running nicely so many thanks i finally got the link running it's great! thanks